# Global sections of a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, projective-schemes, line-bundles

let $X$ be a normal projective curve over field $k$. let $Z=\sum_{x \text{ closed}} n_x [x]$ be a $0$-cycle on $X$ and $D \in Div(X)$ a Cartier divisor such that $[D]=Z$. then $D$ gives rise for a line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. I'm looking for a reference or sketch of the proof of this identity

$$H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D))=\{f\in K(X)^*: \mbox{mult}_x(f)+n_x\geq 0\}\cup \{0\}.$$

Comment: Try to look at Proposition II.7.7 in Hartshorne. In the proof of part (b), there is a very short argument on why that should be the case.

Comment: @Stefano:the argument from 7.7(b) confuses me a bit: we consider divisor $D_0$ defined by system $\{U_i,f_i\}$ and consider a rational function $f \in K = \mathcal{K}(X)$. why $(f) \ge -D_0$ imply that $f$ is a global section of $\mathcal{L}(D_0)$?